# How to select Target mode with only one monitor

Tags: mac, mac-mini, migration

I have hooked a new Mac Mini up to my monitor but want to migrate data from my old Mac Mini to the new one but only have one monitor and Migration Assistant requires that I start the old one up in target mode. With only one monitor. How can I start that old one up in Target mode so the new one can recognize it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to plug a monitor into your old Mac Mini.  Just power it on while holding down the T key and it will go into target disk mode.